# Lock for one rank in having ranks with discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to lock some ranks, to have only one from a board, e.g `tab = [rank1, rank2, rank3, rank4, ...]`.
For example, if I have `rank1`, I can't get `rank2`.
My code is:

```
async def rank(ctx, *, role:discord.Role):
member = ctx.message.author
for i in member.roles:
    for j in tab:
       if j in i:
           if role.name == j:
               await ctx.send(f"You can't get this role")
               return
```

The bot give ranks from this board. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding the improper indentation, [`Member.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.roles) returns a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) of [`Role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role)s, so `i` will be a `Role` object.
`if j in i` will raise a `TypeError` since `Role` objects are not iterable.

If `tab` is a list of `Role` objects, then you can simply check if `i` is in that list.
Otherwise, if it's a list of role names, you can use the `name` attribute of `i` to check if it's in the list.

Comment: So I have: for i in member.roles: if i in tab: if role.name in tab: return. What's wrong?

Comment: Is `tab` a list of `Role` objects or strings with role names? It can't be both, so either `i in tab` or `role.name in tab` will always be `False`, because one is checking for a `Role object` in `tab` and the other is checking for a string.

Comment: The tab have names of roles, so it's string